# SQL Trigger getting invoked more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have an `INSERT TRIGGER` as follows:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TrackingInitialize]
   ON  [dbo].[WorkSchedule_] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @work_area varchar(255);
    DECLARE @schedule_date date;
    DECLARE @employee1 varchar(255);
    DECLARE @hours1 float;

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @work_area=i.WorkArea FROM inserted i;
    SELECT @schedule_date=i.ScheduleDate FROM inserted i;
    SELECT @employee1=i.Employee1 FROM inserted i;
    SELECT @hours1=i.Hours1 FROM inserted i;

    SELECT @ccname = CostCenter_.Name
    FROM WorkArea_, CostCenter_
    WHERE WorkArea_.CostCenterID = CostCenter_.ID and WorkArea_.WorkAreaName = @work_area

    IF (@employee1 is not NULL)
    BEGIN   
        INSERT into dbo.TrackingInfo_ VALUES(@schedule_date, @employee1, @work_area,null,null,null,null,null, null, null,@ccname,null, @hours1, 0.0, @hours1,0.0);
    END
END
```

I am using `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` to `INSERT` new values from my asp.net application. But after each insert my trigger is inserting additional 7 rows of data with employee as null. Query execution is not present inside any loop. How is it possible?

Comment: The sql looks fine.. are you sure that you are not invoking the code in a loop more than once in regards to executing and or calling the `TrackingInitialize` trigger ..can you show the relevant .cs code behind..

Comment: show the .net code, pelase

Comment: Which table is the recipient of these extra rows? Also, as a best practice do not use INSERT INTO dbo.TrackingInfo_ VALUES()... supply an explicit column list, such as INSERT INTO dbo.TrackingInfo_ (ScheduleDate, Employee) VALUES (@schedule_date, @employee1). I am unable to ascertain which column is "employee". I would love to assume it is @employee1, but that is not certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the if statement of the trigger was failing as the employee value was getting assigned as empty and not null. So changed the TRIGGER code as follows:

```
 IF (@employee1 is not NULL AND datalength(@employee1) != 0)
    BEGIN   
        INSERT into dbo.TrackingInfo_ SELECT employee, work_area, null, null, null ,null, null, null, null,
           cc.name, null, hours, 0.0, hours1, 0.0
    FROM inserted i JOIN
         WorkArea_ w 
         ON w.workareaname = i.work_area JOIN
         CostCenter_ cc
         ON w.CostCenterID = cc.ID 
    WHERE employee IS NOT NULL;
    END
```

Now it is working fine. Thanks guys:)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the problem with your trigger is, but it is not programmed correctly.  You are assuming that `inserted` contains only one row, and that is not correct.

Perhaps you want the trigger to do this:

```
    INSERT into dbo.TrackingInfo_
        SELECT employee, work_area, null, null, null ,null, null, null, null,
               cc.name, null, hours, 0.0, hours1, 0.0
        FROM inserted i JOIN
             WorkArea_ w 
             ON w.workareaname = i.work_area JOIN
             CostCenter_ cc
             ON w.CostCenterID = cc.ID 
        WHERE employee IS NOT NULL;
```

I would strongly recommend that you list the columns explicitly in the `insert` as well.

Comment: Code behind:

`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, sqlConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ScheduleDate", newValues["ScheduleDate"] == null ? (object)DBNull.Value:newValues["ScheduleDate"]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("WorkArea", newValues["WorkArea"] == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : newValues["WorkArea"]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Employee1", newValues["Employee1"] == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : newValues["Employee1"]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Hours1", newValues["Hours1"] == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : newValues["Hours1"]);`

Comment: Good point Gordon, I will change the code as suggested. I am guessing the value which is getting assigned to the employee1 variable is empty rather than null, that's why the trigger if statement is failing.